# How to exclude files from being copied, by maven, into the exploded war

Tags: maven, war

I have a Java web app, in which I have some folders within the standard webapp source directory `(src/main/webapp)` that I don't want to get copied over into the war (`exploded` or `packaged`).

One of the reasons I don't want these files copying over is that we run the YUI JS & CSS minimizer & compressor on .js and .css files within the exploded war. The files that I want to exclude produce errors during the compression phase. The other reason I don't want them adding to the war is that they support testing a single page JS app that lives within the webapp (they are client side JS test scripts that rely on `node` / `angular.js`).

Below are the relevant sections from the `POM.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>parent-resources</id>
      <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <overlays>
        </overlays>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-work</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exploded</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use `warSourceExcludes` to exclude certain paths, but to no avail. An example of my usage is shown below, where `client/` is a folder directly beneath `src/main/webapp`:

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <warSourceExcludes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>
        client/
      </exclude>
    </excludes>
  </warSourceExcludes>
  ...
</configuration>
```

What is the correct way to exclude certain paths, and or individual files, within the web app source directory from being included in the exploded war?

## UPDATE

Following on from the suggestion from @maba I updated the configuration as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  <overlays>
  </overlays>                                 
  <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-work</webappDirectory>
  <warSourceExcludes>client/</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
```

The folder, `client/`, still is getting copied across. Any ideas?

Comment: warSourceExcludes is documented as being a comma-separated string, so there shouldn't be any XML in there.  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Comment: question has been updated to reflect correct use - still doesn't work for me though.

Comment: I suspect that there is a further issue with my `pom.xml`. I will look into whether this weeks with pristine project generated from an archetype

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @alexksandr & @maba for their answers - which though correct didn't fully resolve my issue.

The solution seems to be - though I am not sure exactly why this is the case - that the configuration section is not picked up on when it is placed within the `execution` section.

Taking my original pom.xml and re-factoring it to make it work gives:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <overlays>
    </overlays>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-work</webappDirectory>
    <warSourceExcludes>client/</warSourceExcludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>parent-resources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exploded</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The important detail seems to be that the configuration should be at the top level of the plugin and not within the `execution` section - though clearly the `xml` in my first attempt to use `warSourceExcludes` was way off target (see original question prior to the update section).

Comment: That's how maven plugins work. They have either configuration bound to be executed in a build **OR** configuration for command line execution. Take a look at the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) as an example. It is quite specific about how the two configuration parts differ. Your requirements were not totally clear. But it's nice that you now have a working configuration.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - and apollogies if I didn't describe the issue correctly (probably due to me not really getting the finer details of maven). But thanks again maba @aleksandr for your help!

Comment: If you found our answers useful/helpful then upvote them. And accept your own answer if that is what you found to be the best solution.

Comment: yes, apologies. Have up-voted your answers as they were indeed useful. thanks again

Comment: great you mentioned that part on execution section, saved me now 8 years later from the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I could find no configuration of <warSourceExcludes> which worked, however <packagingExcludes> did work:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>excludeMe/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: That solved my problem with minify-maven-plugin, which was keeping the concatenated files in my .war, even with the use of <warSourceExcludes>.

Comment: note that `packagingExcludes` only excludes from the `.war` file, not from the exploded folder

Answer (score 2):

In order to exclude all files from folder use wildcards like that `client/**`

```
<configuration>
 <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
 <overlays>
 </overlays>                                 
 <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-work</webappDirectory>
 <warSourceExcludes>client/**</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `warSourceExcludes` is wrong. Here is what the [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes) says regarding `warSourceExludes`:

> The comma separated list of tokens to exclude when copying the content of the warSourceDirectory.

So in your case this is what your configuration should look like:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <warSourceExcludes>client/</warSourceExcludes>
  ...
</configuration>
```

This means also that if you want to add some more excludes, just add them separated with a comma:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <warSourceExcludes>client/,otherDir/,evenMoreDir/</warSourceExcludes>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi,First off thanks for the response. just tried your suggestion with no luck, Will update my question to include what I have tried. thanks

Comment: I tried with your setup and I got a folder in `target` that ends with `-work` and in that folder there is no sign of the `client` directory.

Comment: Do you want to create a war as well with the same layout? Or is the exploded war the only result you want?

Comment: strange.... I am running `mvn clean war:exploded` and the `client/` still gets copied over. Not sure what is going on here

Comment: forgot to say I want it excluded from the packaged war as well